# TypeError: props.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm extremely new to ReactJS and have been struggling quite a bit. Right now, I'm trying to create a setting in an admin page where the admin can enter text and update a section on the web app's home page. I created `const [aboutBox, setAboutBox] = useState("")` in Home.js and passed it as props to another file. However, every time I try to type anything in the text box on the admin page, it throws the error "TypeError: props.setAboutBox is not a function". I have used the same format to create other functions and those have worked, so I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you guys so much!

```
const HomeAboutForm = (props) => {
    const handleInputChange = event => {
        console.log('handle input change')
        const box = event.target;
        props.setAboutBox({ ...props.aboutBox,box})
        }
    return (
        <form>
            <TextField 
             onSubmit = { event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (!props.aboutBox) return
                const box = event.target;
                props.setAboutBox({ ...props.aboutBox,box})
                console.log(props.aboutBox)
                }}
                placeholder="Enter new text for About Section here"
                multiline
                value={props.aboutBox}   
                variant="outlined"
                rows={4}
                style={{ margin: "10px", width: '600px' }}
                rowsMax={6}
                required
                input type="text" name="name" value={props.aboutBox} onChange={handleInputChange}
                >
                <input type="text" name="name" value={props.aboutBox} onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </TextField>
                <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 

            </form>  
    );
};
```

EDIT: The parent component to HomeAboutForm also has its own parent component, but the code calling HomeAboutForm is

```
            <HomeAboutForm 
            aboutBox = {props.aboutBox}
            setAboutBox = {props.setAboutBox}/>
```

There is however, a function called getChoiceView that is called like `{getChoiceView(pageNum,props)}` and then from there, the function has the code

```
const getChoiceView = (pageNum, props) => {
    switch (pageNum) {
        case 0:
            return <AddPhoto />;
        case 1:
            return <HomeUpdateAboutView 
            aboutBox = {props.aboutBox}
            setAboutBox = {props.setAboutBox}/>;
        case 2:
            return <HomeUpdateStylistForm />;
        default:
            return "Unknown pageView";
    }
};
```

Could how I'm calling getChoiceView be the issue?

Comment: Your problem is int he parent component of `HomeAboutForm`. You need to show us more information on that so that we can help you.

Comment: In the parent component you should have something like:  <HomeAboutForm aboutBox={aboutBox} setAboutBox={setAboutBox} />